# Append lines to a row in a csv file based on the first field in another row

Tags: ruby, csv

New to Ruby, trying to figure out how accomplish this:

I have a .csv file with data like this:

```
D1, Name, Address, Data, Date
D2, 123
D2, 6413
D2, 1207
D1, Name, Address, Data, Date
D2, 789
D1, Name, Address, Data, Date
```

...and so on.

I am to the point where I can get it to append the data from the D2 line after a D1 line to the end of the D1 Row it follows, but it ignores multiple D2 rows.  Basically I need to append the values from all of the D2 rows following each D1 row as one extra field on the end of the D1 row.

Comment: It might be better to show what your desired output should look like.

Comment: Can you post the code you've written so far?

Comment: We need to see your code: " Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Comment: Just tell us what is your expected output.. ?

Answer (score 0):

I am using a string here as input but you should be able to do the same thing with a CSV file. For each line, check if first element contains D1. If yes, add that line to the result, if not, add the last element to the last element of the result.

```
string = "D1, Name, Address, Data, Date
D2, 123
D2, 6413
D2, 1207
D1, Name, Address, Data, Date
D2, 789
D1, Name, Address, Data, Date"

lines, result = string.tr(',', '').lines.map(&:split), []
lines.each{|line| line.first['D1'] ? result << line : result.last << line.last }
p result #=> [["D1", "Name", "Address", "Data", "Date", "123", "6413", "1207"], ["D1", "Name", "Address", "Data", "Date", "789"], ["D1", "Name", "Address", "Data", "Date"]]
```